# Optimal root in shortest path tree (SPT)

Tags: graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I would like to find the "optimal" shortest path tree (SPT) in some undirected weighted graph. As "optimal" SPT, I mean so its maximal path from root to leaf is minimal from any other potential SPTs.

It is quite easy to find SPT from 1 root via Dijkstra's algorithm. So I can run Dijkstra from all vertices and find the "optimal" SPT and its root.

Is there any faster algorithm?

Comment: This is a great question, but I imagine you'll have better luck at [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Link to new question, for future googlers: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116896/optimal-root-in-shortest-path-tree-spt